# Trying to send users to homepage after logout

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building whole new login/register/logout page on my WP website.

```
function site_router() {
    $root = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $url = str_replace($root, '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    if(count($url) == 1 && $url['0'] == 'login') {
        require 'login-register/login-tpl.php';
        die();
    }

    if(count($url) == 1 && $url['0'] == 'register') {
        require 'login-register/register-tpl.php';
        die();
    }

    if(count($url) == 1 && $url['0'] == 'logout') {
        wp_logout();
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
    }
}
```

I want that when users logout, it redirects to my homepage. Do you know what to do ?

Thanks

Comment: If that does not work I would guess that `wp_logout()` is doing something that stops the redirect from getting a chance to run

Comment: The logout works, but i arrive to a 404 error :/

Comment: In that case it's almost certain that your destination URL is simply incorrect. Check that the URL is correct, if it's relative then check that the path is independent on where your WordPress is located, etc.

Comment: try `header("Location: /");`

Answer (score 0):

```
   if((count($url) == 1 && $url['0'] == 'logout') && wp_logout())  {
       wp_redirect( get_site_url(), 301 );
        exit;                     

    }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is to destroy the user session with `session_destroy()` but maybe you're doing it in the `wp_logout()` function.

If you want to redirect to the homepage of the website you don't need to put the complete URL of the wanted page, you only need to call the name and the relative path of the file, like:

`header("Location: my_homepage.php",TRUE,301)`

After the redirect, you need to put  `exit();` to stop the rest of the script to execute.